# How to grep line depending the content present in the next line?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have large file and need to get the required content.

Following is the snippet of my file:

```
/home/user/balaji.C
#include<stdio.h>
/home/user/ass.cpp
/home/user/bss.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
/home/user/ne.txt
#include<stdio.h>
```

I want to grep the only line which are of ".C" or ".cpp" type and followed line should contain "include" word.
The expected out put is :

```
/home/user/balaji.C
/home/user/bss.cpp
```

I tried it but could not grep depending upon next line content.
Any suggestion?

Comment: How about this `grep .c|.cpp examplefilename` .. Isn't it working..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -B 1 include $FILE | grep -E '\.(C|cpp)$'
```

Assuming GNU grep (you tagged Linux), that will pipe every "include" line and *its preceding line* to a grep which filters down to only what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way using awk:

```
awk '/include/ && x ~ /\.(C|cpp)$/{print x;}{x=$0;}' file
```